# Rails - Testing ApplicationController with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to put the common controller actions, index, show, create etc. in the ApplicationController like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json

  def index
    #implementation
  end

  def show
   #implementation
  end

  def update
    #implementation
  end
end
```

The app will only return JSON.

I have written the following spec to test this with RSPEC's annonymous controller

```
describe ApplicationController do
  controller do ; end

  describe 'Get :index' do
    it 'should respond to index' do
      get :index

      response.code.should eq "200"
    end
  end
end
```

The above spec gives the following error:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template anonymous/index,
>   application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:  *
>   "#"

Can anyone suggest a way to make this work with the anonymous controller?

Comment: Does using `xhr :get :index` instead of `get :index` help?

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it helpful

your controller like

```
def index
end
```

your rspec testing like

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "should respond to index" do
    get :index
    response.code.should eq "200"
  end
end
```

**create index.html.erb in your application/ folder**

then test it.

Comment: in the index action write render :nothing => true and then test.

Comment: The index action will return something.  Do you mean override it in the spec?  This will test nothing then.

Answer (score 0):

describe "GET index" do

```
it "returns correct JSON" do
  # @groups.should have(2).items
  get :index, :format => :json
  response.should be_success
  body = JSON.parse(response.body)
  body.should include('group')
  groups = body['group']
  groups.should have(2).items
  groups.all? {|group| group.key?('customers_count')}.should be_true
  groups.any? {|group| group.key?('customer_ids')}.should be_false
end
```

end